# HTTP 400 for graph /sites endpoint - Error authenticating with resource

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm getting an HTTP 400 on a request for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=* but expected response is an HTTP 200 w/ data.

It works successfully in multiple client environments (i.e. 100s of environments), but it doesn't work for one of our clients.

The application does successfully return calls for /groups, /domains, and other endpoints prior to hitting this HTTP 400.

The error is:

```
Error authenticating with resource
```

Response from remote side is:

```
{
  "code": "AuthenticationError",
  "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "1d68c066-dba8-487e-b3a8-bd77f517d394",
    "date": "2019-06-25T18:50:31"
  }
}
```

I'm not sure the next steps from here. HTTP 400 suggests a malformed request, but I'm guessing this should actually be an HTTP 403 or 401 response instead of a 400?

Not sure how to resolve, please let me know, thanks!

edit: request-id added back in

Comment: If you add back in the `request-id` we can take a look at what the specific auth error was. As it stands my only guess is that maybe it's related to the tenant root site being locked down?

Comment: request-id added back, thanks! I know that other requests (i.e. /groups) complete successfully. Not sure if that helps in debugging "tenant root site being locked down"

Comment: It looks like Graph is unable to get a token to talk to SharePoint for this specific tenant, and so the call to `/sites` isn't even being made. We'll need one of the Graph folks to offer suggested fixes.

Comment: Thanks Brad. Do I need to reach out to them separately or can you let them know to take a look at this thread?

Comment: This should be sufficient - I'll make sure they see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to call other resources the same way (i.e. /groups), it would suggest a lack of permissions. Be sure the app or user authenticating has the required permissions:
`Delegated (work or school account): Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All`
`Delegated (personal Microsoft account): Not supported.`
`Application: Sites.Read.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All`

[Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs)

Comment: Yep, confirmed we have application Sites.Read.All. Still doesn’t work for this client. (Same permissions / api calls work for a lot of other clients)

Comment: How are you authenticating?